# laravel pdf to view add watermark using( Barryvdh\DomPDF)

Tags: laravel

my problem(not show pdf contents when this url(127.0.0.1:8081/php_tutorial.pdf))

Controller

```
public function generatePDF()

{
    $data = [

        'title' => 'Welcome to ',
        'pdf' => '127.0.0.1:8081/php_tutorial.pdf',
        'date' => date('m/d/Y')

    ];
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf',$data);
    $pdf->setPaper('L');
    $pdf->output();
    $canvas = $pdf->getDomPDF()->getCanvas();
    $height = $canvas->get_height();
    $width = $canvas->get_width();
    $canvas->set_opacity(.2,"Multiply");
    $canvas->page_text($width/5, $height/2, 'This Is Watermark text', null,
     70, array(0,0,0),2,2,-30);
     return $pdf->stream('result.pdf'); 

}
```

view (blade)

## {{ $title }}

```
<iframe src="{{ $pdf }}" width="100%" height="500px">
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, explain what situation you have, what ideally you want and what you get in more elaborative manner, than just posting code

Comment: Can you please tell us what issue you are facing?

Comment: how to show (127.0.0.1:8081/php_tutorial.pdf) in my balde(view)

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly You need to create view to load all your PDF Views.
2. Then in your controller query your data

   ```
   public function PDFSlip($id)

      $data = ModelName::get()

      $customPaper = array(0,0,600.00,310.80);

      $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf\bookingDetailPDF', compact('data'))- 
      >setPaper($customPaper, 'portrait');;
      return $pdf->download('PDFNAME.pdf');
   }
   ```
3. Then your file will be downloaded in the local directory and also pdf is loaded into the new tab.